# Create Couchbase Index on Array field

Tags: indexing, couchbase

Hi how to create index on array field my sample doc is

```
   { 
"name": [     {
      "family": "Smith",
      "given": [
        "Kam"
      ],
      "prefix": [
        "Mrs."
      ],
      "use": "official"
    },
    {
      "family": "Johns",
      "given": [
        "Kam"
      ],
      "use": "maiden"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to write a search query (like) on family and given fields ...How to create a index and suggest query ..Im new to couchbase

Comment: Is this for Couchbase or Couchbase Lite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query that selects the customers with family name "Smith" and given name "Kam":

```
select * from customer
where any n in name satisfies n.family = 'Smith' and 
          any fn in n.given satisfies fn = 'Kam' end end
```

Note the use of a nested ANY clause because of the use of a nested array in the data.

You can then create an index on the family name like this:

```
CREATE INDEX customer_name ON customer
   ( DISTINCT ARRAY n.family FOR n IN name END)
```

The index gets used without any hints. You can see that it is being used by adding EXPLAIN to the beginning of the query. That will get you a query plan in JSON that includes an index scan operator.

You can learn more about array indexing here:
https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/indexing-arrays.html

Comment: not sure if it will scan the entire index, or if it will know how to apply a start-stop key.  Sounds like it will have to scan all entries in the index.